# Refine with RDF extension: literals or resources?

Tags: rdf, linked-data, openrefine, turtle-rdf, google-refine

I am using Refine with RDF Extension to produce triples from a CSV. I have imported two vocabularies and am now using them to describe the columns:
[image: RDF Schema Alignment]

How can I change the nodes to describe **resources** rather than **literals**? For example, when I preview the Turtle representation, the triples map to literals, such as *geolink:hasDocumentType* "datasets":
[image: RDF preview Turtle]

Can I create empty nodes in Refine to hold the place of resources, such as **Document Type**? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is assigned in the dialog for the mapping. See "The cell's content is used ..." and then choose "as a URI".

[image]

(sorry for the broken dialog rendering)

Then you choose "Use custom expression" where you can make up your own URI scheme. In this example I simply add the value of the cell to a fix URI pattern:

```
"http://classifications.data.admin.ch/municipality/"+value
```

In the preview you can directly see if this is what you need.

If I need to do more complex things I usually create simple key-value like RDF, so technically not really a graph yet. Then I write a bunch of SPARQL CONSTRUCT queries to clean up the data and transform it into a "real" graph. I found that for many things easier and faster. You can see some examples on [Github](https://github.com/zazuko/fso-lod/tree/master/construct/eCH0071)

Comment: I noticed in an example that I can set "nodeType" to "cell-as-literal" or "cell-as-resource". How can I configure this in Refine?

Comment: Also, is there a way to export the RDF skeleton?

Comment: Where did you find these nodeTypes? Can't remember seeing them. Regarding export, the only way to export a configuration is by copying it from the [undo/redo change history](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/History) in OpenRefine. You will get a JSON structure with the commands.